Angular ng-rough-notation terminate the server- window is not defined
I wanted to implement the rough notation library:
https://github.com/jornetsimon/ng-rough-notation
but using it
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RoughNotationModule } from 'ng-rough-notation';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-section-main-text',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RoughNotationModule],
  templateUrl: './hero-section-main-text.component.html',
  styleUrl: './hero-section-main-text.component.css',
})
export class HeroSectionMainTextComponent {}

and html
<span roughNotation>Some content</span>

causes:
ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined

and kills running server.
How to fix it?
